# How to put a button in middle of the UIView Horizontally and Vertically for any device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rubymotion

I have a UIButton of type UIButtonRoundedRectType that I want to put in middle of the screen horizontally and vertically.

I've tried doing this by hardcoding numbers but this looks back when run on iPhone vs. iphone (retina). I would like to programmatically keep the button in the center by calculating the container's width.

So, I've tried this but it doesn't work.

```
container = view.frame.size
button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
button.frame = [[container.width/2-button.frame.size.width/2,150], [280,50]]
```

Comment: You can do this using Storyboards using layout constraints. That way you don't have to worry about hard coding anything. http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: What doesn't work?  What are you using for "view"?

Comment: (Keep in mind that the above will only center within "view".  If "view" is not centered then the button will be equally off-center.)

Comment: the view is a UIViewController

Answer (score 10):

Simple approach:

```
button.center = view.center;
```

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
button.center = [button.superview convertPoint:button.superview.center fromView:button.superview.superview];
```

Answer (score 2):

You weren't too far off. This works (I tried it):

```
container = view.frame.size
button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonTypeRoundedRect)
button_size = [ 280, 50 ]
left_margin = (container.width / 2) - (button_size[0] / 2)
top_margin = (container.height / 2) - (button_size[1] / 2)
button.frame = [[ left_margin, top_margin ], button_size ]
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using view in XIB you can use like that i have mentioned.

GO to XIB -> Click on View -> Click on Size Inspector -> Arrange (You can set position here).

[image]

Select all properties of `Position of Container` and `Fill Container`.

And if you creating view dynamically(not in XIB) then you can use according superview's bounds.